# How to find duplicate values in database with Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder

How can I find duplicate values in database with Laravel. I want the results like this:

*name_data* - *amount*

(Column name along with amount of duplicate data)

I used this code but it didn't work:

```php
$duplicates = DB::table('jadwals')
    ->select('nama_peserta', (DB::raw('COUNT(nama_peserta)')))
    ->groupBy('nama_peserta')
    ->having(DB::raw('COUNT(nama_peserta)  > 1'))
    ->get();
```

Please help me, thank you!

Comment: I would rewrite ->select('nama_peserta', (DB::raw('COUNT(nama_peserta)'))) to ->selectRaw('nama_peserta, COUNT(nama_peserta)')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error with `having DB::raw()`, 
try:

```php
->having(DB::raw('COUNT(nama_peserta)'), '>', 1)
```

or

```php
->havingRaw('COUNT(nama_peserta) > 1')
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, my code is finally running.
Thankyou so much @TsaiKoga